# How to convert numbers properly into polyline points

Tags: html, math, svg, polyline

I need to fill in data in the polyline points, the problem is that my data representing each data set should not be above 120.

If I have these numbers

5000
5320
5400
5100
4950
4850

I need to fit them into the polyline points which at maximum should be 120 and minimum 0.
How do I do this, ive thought about different ways to do this like below:

```
$total = "The Total Value Of All Datasets"
$row['value'] = "The Value Of The Current Dataset";

$point = ceil (($row['value'] / $total) * 1200);
```

The above example will render very close numbers which are not ideal since I need the biggest to represent 120 and the lowest 0 and the others a number in between.

A static sample of the SVG and the Polyline

```
    <svg viewBox="0 0 500 100" class="mktcap_spark">
    <polyline
        fill="none"
        stroke="#e9be3d"
        stroke-width="8"
        points="
        00,120
        20,60
        40,120
        60,10
        80,80
        100,80
        120,60
        140,100
        160,90
        180,80
        200, 110
        220, 10
        240, 70
        260, 100
        280, 100
        300, 40
        320, 0
        340, 100
        360, 100
        380, 120
        400, 60
        420, 70
        440, 80
        460, 20
        480, 50
        500, 30
        "
        />

    </svg>
```

Renders this

Comment: search the data, find the lowest and highest numbers, scale accordingly. Or better yet just use a transform and leave the numbers alone.

Comment: @RobertLongson a transform?

Comment: https://www.w3.org/TR/SVG11/coords.html#TransformAttribute

Comment: What's a polyline?  Do you mean piecewise fitting using polynomials or splines?  Do you mean least squares fitting using an assumed polynomial order of your choosing?  Are these pairs of (x, y) points?  Your question is not clear to me.

Comment: @duffymo a polyline is a HTML element :)

Comment: Sorry, the math tag threw me.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Find minimal and maximal value `$xMin, $xMax`, then use linear mapping

```
$newX = 120 * ($X - $xMin) / ($xMax - $xMin)
```

Comment: Thanks, this works great, looking into linear mapping

Comment: Had to rearrange some variables to achieve the correct visuals $newX = ceil(120 * ($X - $h) / ($l - $h));